# flot chart loading from database

Tags: php

i have this code for bar chart but i want to load the data for mysql database

```
/*
 * BAR CHART
 * ---------
 */

var bar_data = {
  data: [["20-30", 10], ["31-40", 8], ["41-50", 4], ["51-60", 13]],
  color: "#3c8dbc"
};
$.plot("#bar-chart", [bar_data], {
  grid: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "#f3f3f3",
    tickColor: "#f3f3f3"
  },
  series: {
    bars: {
      show: true,
      barWidth: 0.5,
      align: "center"
    }
  },
  xaxis: {
    mode: "categories",
    tickLength: 0
  }
});
/* END BAR CHART */
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have tried so far? This is a broad question and SO is not a coding service. You have to put atleast some effort to solve your own problem, before others are willing to help. Please check out how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

There are some hacky ways of using `json_encode` to output a PHP array in between some `<script>` tags as one solution.

The better solution though is often to use AJAX to request the data back as JSON and initialize your graph from that. In this way, you are not creating global javascript data variables outside of your javascript.